# PHP - redirect if there isn't a cookie or another cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I have cookie A and cookie B, and want to redirect to Google if no cookies are present, but if one of the two is present must not redirect.

I have made/try this one:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['Access']) || !isset($_COOKIE['Guest'])) {
header ("location: https://www.google.com"); }
```

but without success... How can i solve it? Thanks

Comment: You got your logic wrong. It should be `&&`.

Comment: You have reason, true... :( Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to redirect when **NONE** of your cookies are present, then you need the **AND** (`&&`) operator not the **OR** (`||`).

```
|| => OR
```

and

```
&& => AND
```

therefore

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['Access']) || !isset($_COOKIE['Guest'])) {
```

should be

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['Access']) && !isset($_COOKIE['Guest'])) {
```

**Reading Material**

[Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)